# How to add my key to this google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, key, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I need to update this script to pass my key so that I don't go over the limit per day. How would I modify this script to pass my key?

(NOTE: google class information found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder)

```
    function geo2zip(a) {
      var response=Maps.newGeocoder()
        .reverseGeocode(lat(a),long(a));
      return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',')[2].trim().split(' ')[1];
    }
    function lat(pointa) {
     var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
         .geocode(pointa);
      return response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
    }
    function long(pointa) {
      var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
         .geocode(pointa);
      return response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
    }
```

I have never used a google apps script before.

I have this script in place and am using "=geo2zip(cell)" to call the script from my google sheet to get the zip code for incomplete addresses. There are ~28k in my sheet. I have enabled the geocoding api in my google console and my billing info. and created my key but am not sure how to include my key in the script above.

I have also tried using the following to call the api using my key. It is working, but this has resulted in VERY slow responses. At the rate it is taking these to respond, it will take me 10 days to finish updating my 28k records.

CELL M4852--> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=ADDRESS&key=MYKEY"
NEXT CELL--> "=ImportXML(M4852,"/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")"

The script responds much more quickly, so I would prefer to use that and pass my key. Please let me know if you can help.

UPDATE: I was able to resolve this using Alberto's suggestion below of adding the Maps.setAuthentication.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe what have you tried and where did you get stuck. Also refer to this document on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you @Gustavo I have updated my question above to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue has more to do with the Google API management than with the scripts themselves. There is a way to limit how much your key is used. According to the Maps Platform documentation:

> Manage Your Cost of Use
>
> To manage your cost of use of the Google Maps
>   Platform APIs, you can set daily limits to all requests to any
>   billable API.
>
> To view or change daily billable limits for the Geocoding API, do the
>   following:
>
> Go to the Geocoding API Quotas page in the Google Cloud Platform
>   Console. From the projects list, select a project. In the Requests
>   section, on the Requests per day line, click the edit icon, then enter
>   the preferred total billable daily quota, up to the limit (if any)
>   specified by Google.

You can basically set how many requests you want to allow per day, which will avoid you going over your limit.

**UPDATE**

You can link the script to your account using the `Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey)` method, according to the docs, it:

> Enables the use of an externally established Maps API for Business
>   account, to leverage additional quota allowances. Your client ID and
>   signing key can be obtained from the Google Enterprise Support Portal.
>   Set these values to null to go back to using the default quota
>   allowances.

Map Documentation Link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)

Quotas URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/apiui/apiview/geocoding_backend/quotas?_ga=2.141719605.643331044.1560431279-1498828710.1560431279

Documentation URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing

Comment: Thanks Alberto. I have updated my quotas. The script doesn't seem to be connected to my account at all. So I think the limit error it is giving me is because it only allows ~200 updates without a key per day. Whereas, the other formula fields I am using are passing my key so I'm not running into any limit errors when using those. But those are taking way longer to get a response for. So, I'm hoping to update the script to pass my key instead. Do you know how I would update the script to pass my key?

Comment: I see what you mean, I found that you can link the script to your account using the `Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey)` method, according to the docs, it: "Enables the use of an externally established Maps API for Business account, to leverage additional quota allowances. Your client ID and signing key can be obtained from the Google Enterprise Support Portal. Set these values to null to go back to using the default quota allowances." Link: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setauthenticationclientid-signingkey]

Comment: Thanks Alberto! I am looking for my client id and signing key. So far, I can only find my API Key name and API Key. I'll keep looking.