# How to add API key to Google Geocoding script

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, geocode

I am asking a very similar question to this post: [How to add my key to this google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580773/how-to-add-my-key-to-this-google-app-script)

However, the answer on that post no longer works (to use Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey)) since it was for use for a Google Maps API Premium Plan, which is no longer available for new customers.
See here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)

Basically, I am using the below code to look up zip codes for a 10,000 item list of addresses in google sheets. The code works, but I am getting a "Service invoked too many times for one day: geocode (line 7)" error. I generated a geocode API key and billing account, but cannot figure out where to insert it. I am not very familiar with google script code.

```
    function geo2zip(a) {
  var response=Maps.newGeocoder()
    .reverseGeocode(lat(a),long(a));
  return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',')[2].trim().split(' ')[1];
}
function lat(pointa) {
 var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
     .geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
}
function long(pointa) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
     .geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, you can't! The AppScript libraries aren't designed for doing this. You have to stay in the allowed free tier.

For using your API key, you have to call [directly the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse). There is no big change compare to your current version

```
var YOUR_API_KEY=.......

function geo2zip(a) {
  var options = {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      contentType: "application/json",
  };

  var serviceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat(a) + "," + long(a) + "&key=" + YOUR_API_KEY;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',')[2].trim().split(' ')[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So it seems no matter what I will be limited to the quota of 300 queries per day? If so, is there an alternate way to accomplish my goal here (ie fetch zip codes for a long list of 10000+ addresses)? Appreciate any advice or just being pointed in the right direction....at this point I am kind of lost for how to solve this

Comment: Not sure that AppScript is the best place for doing this (10k+ address is a lot of query! I hope you want do it every day, it will be expensive!). Cloud Function or Cloud Run will be more designed for this. But take care to the timeouts. I strongly recommend you to process chunk of 1000 lines for examples. By the way you will be scalable!

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will look into those